# Is it plausible to draw an enthalpy diagram for a nuclear reaction?

Tags: kinetics, energy, nuclear-chemistry

For a project I am required to draw a enthalpy diagram for the conversion of thorium-232 to uranium-233 and I am unsure on how to proceed. I understand a certain amount of energy is lost through beta decay, but would beta decay be considered a reaction?

Comment: Generally, a chemical reaction only applies to changes in the arrangement of electrons (ie bonds forming/breaking). Beta decay could be described as a nuclear reaction. You can still diagram the transition and how it affects the energy of the particles involved.